# Reading moisture sensor data and activating water pump causing infinite loop?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, micropython

I'm trying to interact with a moisture sensor and 3.3v submersible water pump to create an auto watering system, i'm currently prototyping and have run into an issue

When the code runs, it seems to get stuck on on setting the gpio_pin to high/moisture gets printed out once and never again. Not entirely sure whats happening..

```
# import required modules
from machine import ADC, Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C
import utime
 
# use variables instead of numbers:
soil = ADC(Pin(26)) # Soil moisture PIN reference
gpio_pin = machine.Pin(15, machine.Pin.OUT)

#Calibraton values
min_moisture=19200
max_moisture=49300
 
readDelay = 0.5 # delay between 
 
while True:
    # read moisture value and convert to percentage into the calibration range
    moisture = (max_moisture-soil.read_u16())*100/(max_moisture-min_moisture) 
    # print values
    print("moisture: " + "%.2f" % moisture +"% (adc: "+str(soil.read_u16())+")")
    
    if moisture < 80:
        gpio_pin.value(1)
        utime.sleep(2)
        gpio_pin.value(0)
    else:
        gpio_pin.value(0)
 
    utime.sleep(readDelay) # set a delay between readings
```

the output is this:

```
moisture: 2.53% (adc: 48347)
```

Comment: Did you test `gpio_pin.value(1); sleep(...); gpio_pin.value(0)` alone, without any reading and any loop?

Comment: Yeah that works, im just wondering why print has stopped workig

Comment: Are you sure you aren't just rewriting the same line repeatedly?